# MariaDB UPDATE large table in little chunks

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb

I want to know how to write a procedure that updates a large table in little chunks. There are tons of examples but in 90% of them people use TOP or ROWCOUNT which is not available in MariaDB and 10% that are ridiculously complex.

(update)
This is the code I want to execute on little chunks.

```
UPDATE b_accounts BA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE * AMOUNT_UNIT * AMOUNT) TOTAL_AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE
        ,ACCOUNT_ID
    FROM b_orders
    GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
    ) BO ON BA.ACCOUNT_ID = BO.ACCOUNT_ID
SET BA.TOTAL_AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE = BO.TOTAL_AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE;
```

Inside `b_accounts` TABLE there are OVER 200k records. I still want TO
`UPDATE TOTAL_AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE` but 10k each iteration

Comment: show your related schema and a sample of your goal .

Comment: IMHO, it looks like you applying the wrong method to the actual problem. checkout my answer and give comment if you don't agree.

Comment: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are counterparts to `TOP`.  See [_Tips on chunking_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig), including why not to use `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your procedure will work BUT it is not an efficient and effective ways to update real-time online data that account for changes.

A batch processing procedure is only as good as the processing time. What if 10 records change in b_orders, are you going to run the whole procedure again for the 200k records?  No matter how efficient is your "chunk", your b_account are always outdated when there is changes. (I don't understand why people suggest those TOP , ROWCOUNT while didn't see the actual data CUD problem)

For efficiency and simple to understand, you should(MUST in your case) create a complete CUD triggers for b_orders table.

The idea of CUD(create, update, delete) triggers is pretty simple : Whenever there is an changes action in b_orders table, just carry out the calculation and store it into b_accounts.TOTAL_AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE.

An example of NEW record triggers,  it is very simple

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_ AFTER BEFORE INSERT ON b_orders
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE b_accounts 
  SET  b_accounts.TOTAL_AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE = 
  (  SELECT SUM(AVG_DELIVERY_PRICE * AMOUNT_UNIT * AMOUNT) 
     from b_orders
     where ACCOUNT_ID = NEW.ACCOUNT_ID )
  WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = NEW.ACCOUNT_ID 
END;
```

Create similar action for update, delete. 
NOTE : I don't guarantee the above trigger syntax correctness, please write your own.  This answer just to give you idea to solve your issue.

Then to "refresh" the b_accounts table, you need to run an dummy update on b_orders tables by picking record with unique ACCOUNT_ID(so you don't repeat the update process when come into same account_id in the b_orders table) . The trigger will refresh your b_orders for now and in the future.